# Popover view with arrow on iPhone

Tags: ios, uiview, uipopovercontroller, ios-autolayout

I need to present a UI in a popover with arrow which has few controls that works on both iPhone and iPad. I am not sure what is the best way to do this that works correctly with Autolayout and resizing. Let's say I have a UIButton, UISlider, UIButton, UISlider in that order which are equally spaced vertically in the view, how do I set Autolayout constraints and present the view as popover that adapts to resizing? There are essentially two questions here -- how to display a view as popover with arrow and how to use autolayout to adapt to presentation size.

Comment: Can you please share the design.

Comment: I fail to show popover on iPhone using UIPopoverPresentationController. It shows full screen modally. Can you help?